# How do I get a virtual in mongoose, If a property is deselected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

lets say I have post Model and schema contains **UserId** , **Title**, **Desc** and **likes** array which takes userId's as ref

when I make a query I get a virtual property like this to find out num of like of a post would have

```
schema.virtual("numLikes").get(function () {
  return this.likes.length;
});
```

But the problem is when I run the **findById()** Method I dont want to get likes from database because likes array would contain large list of users

```
 const post = await Post.findById(postId).select("-likes -shares");
```

so how do I get Likes count without fetching likes array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be done using aggregation, by using the `$size` operators in a projection:

```
const aggregate = Post.aggregate([
  { $match: {_id: postId}},
  { $project: {
      numberOfLikes: { $size: "$likes" }
    }
  }
]);
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-project